# Actions Within SSRS Maps

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reporting-services-map

I am working on a SSRS report service that has a map which I manage to link it with a tablix through a parameter [Country]. My objective is whenever the user click on a specified coloured country to drill though, the map will direct the user to the tablix via the parameter.
The problem is, if I click to a country that is not in the range of the required, the map randomly directs me to the tablix!
For example, when I click on China, the map directs me to the records of South Africa in the tablix.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `not in the range of the required`? And what would be the desired result when it is not in range? And can you give us some sample data/screenshot and a desired result?

Comment: Hiya NickyvV, thank you for your reply. In my map I have the top 50% selling places in the world, only 4 countries. Whenever I click on one of those countries, I would be directed to a report that holds the details of this specific country. However, all countries are also hyperlinked and can be clicked, once I click to any country randomly the map direct me to the report. Even though the country type is not existed in the report!

Comment: The required result should strictly associated to the countries specified in the map. Also this can be changed dynamically if new countries would be highlighted. I will explain more if needed :)

Comment: OK, so how are the links from the countries to your tablix created on the map? Can you filter for creating the links for only the top 50%?

Comment: I created a hidden parameter in the tablix for the countries. The tablix uses the OLAP calculation I created on the hierarchy. The tablix and the map are both using the same dataset, the same calculations, but in the tablix I use more details about each countries sales. The hidden parameter in the tablix is linked with the COUNTRY property in the map through the action